# Urban airship and android in mobile data

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am using Urban Airship service for my android app. When trying to push during the mobile data usage didn't receive any push messages. After that try I have turned on the Wi-Fi. Immediately I can receive the push message which is couldn't receive in mobile data.

My query is , Is Urban Airship only pushes the message in Wi-Fi data connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urban Airship don't push the data themselves. They use Google Cloud Messaging. Google Cloud Messaging works for both mobile data and WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that it takes some time for Google Cloud Messaging to refresh your ip when you switch network like that. It's one of the issues with it. Try waiting a bit longer before you send a new notification.